# jQuery Chosen option values

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen jQuery plugin. I have a standard single select that looks like that:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a country..." id="country">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

With Chosen, I end up with something like that:

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Afghanistan</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Albania</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Algeria</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a simple way to keep the option values (AF,AL,DZ) in the list elements with Chosen, like a data-value or such attribute? I could not find that in the docs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jquery-chosen just adds to your select element just 'display: none'. 
So you could take all your values from it.

```
$('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
 alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. I know my select element is still there and hidden. When I select an element with Chosen, it does not reflect the selection in the HTML select element. I was just asking if there was an option or an easy way to add the option values to the list elements with Chosen.

Comment: In my case it is revlecting. I tested it here http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ (Version 1.0.0). May be you used different version. Code sample added to answer.